# ¿Por qué no me retorna los valores verdaderos?

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que la función `seAbre(horarios,minimo)` debería retornar `true`  si hay igual o más cantidad de números negativos o ceros en el array `horarios` que el numero `minimo`, y `false` si esto no sucede. Sin embargo, me retorna siempre `false` y no entiendo por qué.

```
function seAbre(horarios,minimo){
    let aTiempo = 0;
    for(let i =0 ;i< horarios.length;i++){
        if(horarios[i]<=0){
            aTiempo ++;
        }
        if(aTiempo >= minimo){
              return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function seAbre(horarios,minimo){
    let aTiempo = 0;
    for(let i =0 ;i< horarios.length;i++){
        if(horarios[i]<=0){
            aTiempo ++;
        }
        if(aTiempo >= minimo){
              return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }

    }
}

console.log(seAbre([4, 5, -1], 1));
```

Como vemos no funciona bien, retorna `false` como tu dices, sin embargo... y esto a que se debe?

Para darnos cuenta del porque de este comportamiento debemos definir y a la vez recordar tres sentencias basicas, `return`, `break` y `continue`.

Donde `return` hace parte de cualquier cosa que sea una función y `break` y `continue` solo hacen parte de los ciclos.

`return`: hace que la función 'hable', es decir que nos devuelva a nosotros un valor que podamos usar fuera de la función, **todo lo que este debajo de return no será ejecutado**.

`break`: rompe el ciclo en el que te encuentras para seguir con la ejecución del código.

`continue`: salta a la siguiente ejecución del ciclo (si es que hay una proxima).

El problema se encuentra es en el `return`, debido a lo que dijimos antes **'lo que sea que este debajo de return ya no será ejecutado'**, y cuando nosotros ponemos un `return` dentro de un ciclo, el `return` comienza a funcionar como si hubiesemos puesto un `break` statement en el ciclo, es decir, se sale del ciclo y directamente detiene la ejecución de nuestra función en ese punto.

Y esto que tiene que ver con el problema??

Pues que sí por ejemplo, al momento de contar todos los tiempos, aún no se ha llegado al minimo requerido el resultado siempre va ser `false` y en tu caso en la mayoria de casos nunca se van a llegar a contar todos los casos debido al `return` statement que pusiste (no se alcanza a sumar todas las coincidencias de tu condición).

Para solucionarlo solo debes hacer uso de return cuando ya tengas toda tu información, es decir **cuando el ciclo haya hecho lo suyo y no antes**.

checa el siguiente código corregido:

```js
function seAbre(horarios,minimo){
    let aTiempo = 0;
    for(let i =0 ;i< horarios.length;i++){
        if(horarios[i]<=0){
            aTiempo ++;
        }
    }
    
    if(aTiempo >= minimo){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(seAbre([4, 5, -1], 1));
```

Como vemos ahora funciona correctamente, y lo unico que tuvimos que hacer es esperar a que el ciclo hiciese lo suyo para poder retornar ya sea `true` o `false`.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que controlas la cantidad de números <= 0 dentro del for, por lo cual la primera vez que pregunta si `aTiempo >= minimo`, `aTiempo` será 0 o 1. Debes hacer esa pregunta luego de haber terminado de contar los menores a cero

```
function seAbre(horarios,minimo){
    let aTiempo = 0;
    for(let i = 0 ; i < horarios.length; i++){
        if(horarios[i] <= 0){
            aTiempo ++;
        }    
    }

    if(aTiempo >= minimo){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Una cosa que siempre se puede hacer cuando devuelves true cuando tu condición es true y false cuando tu condición es false, es directamente devolver el resultado de esa condicion. Ejemplo:

```
function seAbre(horarios, minimo) {
    let cantidad_cero_o_menos = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < horarios.length; i++) {
        if(horarios[i] <= 0) {
            cantidad_cero_o_menos++;
        }
    }
    return cantidad_cero_o_menos >= minimo;
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Por qué usas “let” en lugar de “var”? Es por algo en particular? Proba definir la variable aTiempo simplemente como “var aTiempo = 0;” y sacar los condicionales del return del bloque for, y contame que pasa...

Comment: Let se usa para declarar variables de tipo bloque, así como lo había dicho beta... realmente esto de usar var o let no afectaria al ejercicio. es mas bien una cuestion de gustos y de control de variables...

Comment: Si entiendo, pero creía que el uso correcto de let es cuando tenés otros casos, no como este que se puede resolver tranquilamente con un var

Comment: Tampoco funcionaria con var, var no resuelve el problema ni let tampoco en este caso, el problema no es var o let.

Comment: No, eso esta claro, el problema esta en el uso de las "}" pero obviando eso pensaba que el let se usa en otros casos donde var no serviría

Answer (score -1):

Debe ser porque la validacion if(aTiempo >= minimo esta dentro del cilo for, ponla fuera del ciclo. Se valida y entra al return false porque al principio siempre da false. Y el Return sirve para terminar la funcion. Es decir, solo se cumple el ciclo una vez porque no se recorre todo el array.

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor ampliar tu respuesta?, pues ¿qué pasa si necesita evaluar con da valor iterado por el ciclo?

Comment: Que se valida y entra al return false porque al principio siempre da false. Y el Return sirve para terminar la funcion. Es decir, solo se cumple el ciclo una vez.

Comment: Esto que me explicas enriquecerá el contenido de tu pregunta, considera editarla y agregarlo así el OP la comprenderá mejor

Comment: ciclo while?, no se esta usando un while en la pregunta.

Comment: Perdon, mi error jajaja ciclo for